# Where does password is stored in auth0 dashboad

Tags: auth0

I would like to know where the password field is shown in dashboard. I cant see in password field in user profile object. How can I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't see the password for a user (only a secure password hash is stored, so Auth has no way of getting the actual value). As a dashboard administrator, you can however change the password using the red **Actions** drop down list, and then selecting **Change Password**.

[image: Dashboard image]